# Alternative to decorate function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

Since TypeScript allows decorate only class, method, property or setter/getter because of hoisting, is there any way to decorate a raw function? Or maybe something similar to decoration mechanism or even write own custom mechanism to avoid TypeScript rules. Thanks.

Comment: Make a wrapper? What exactly are you trying to do with decoration?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is not one of the "TypeScript rules" but a problem with JavaScript. It is yet not syntactically possible to use  `@decorator` for functions, but in its essence, a function decorator is just a higher-order function that wraps around the decorated function.

The closest thing that you can do is defining a function wrapper

```
function foo() {
    return "asd";
}

const wrap = (func: () => void) => {
    const wrapped = () => {
         console.log("wrapped");
         return func();
    }
    return wrapped;
}

console.log(wrap(foo)());
```

Comment: Just adding some pitfalls for less experienced devs: 1. `wrap(foo)` returns a **new** (wrapped) function, it doesn't overwrite `foo()`. But you can do it yourself `foo = wrap(foo);` 2. `wrap(function foo(){ ... })` here you're dealing with a function expression, not statement. There is no hoisted `function foo()` in this case and if you want to call it as `foo` you need to assign it to some variable, like `const foo = wrap(function...);`